# Stopped (closed by home button) android app crashes on orientation change

Tags: android, crash, screen-orientation, samsung-mobile

When active my app is handling screen orientation changes sufficiently and is stable.

But if the app is not visible (after pressing the home button) the app crashes on screen orientation change (I see the home screen and I see the homes screen turn to landscape) with following error:

```
02-10 14:24:00.361    1660-1660/de.mydomain.MyApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.mydomain.MyApp, PID: 1660
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.initClose(ActionBarContextView.java:330)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onConfigurationChanged(ActionBarContextView.java:185)
        at android.view.View.dispatchConfigurationChanged(View.java:8599)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1105)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateConfiguration(ViewRootImpl.java:3441)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3612)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.initClose(ActionBarContextView.java:330)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onConfigurationChanged(ActionBarContextView.java:185)
            at android.view.View.dispatchConfigurationChanged(View.java:8599)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1105)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateConfiguration(ViewRootImpl.java:3441)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3612)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=24; index=230
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
        at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:459)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:721)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:125)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1509)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:908)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.initClose(ActionBarContextView.java:330)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onConfigurationChanged(ActionBarContextView.java:185)
            at android.view.View.dispatchConfigurationChanged(View.java:8599)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1105)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchConfigurationChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateConfiguration(ViewRootImpl.java:3441)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3612)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It would be difficult for me to show you the whole code of the MainActivity since it has a number of superclasses and instantiates several custom objects. The MainActivity shows a list by the use of an adapter and uses database connections.

This is where the view is inflated:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    this.showList(); }


 protected void showList() { 
 this.makeListView();//asignes the ListView to this.listview
 this.makeListHelper();//listHelper is building the list to be shown

 this.arrayAdapter = new MyListItemStringAdapter(this,this.listHelper.getList());
 this.listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 this.listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                      int position, long id)
     {  didSelectItem(position);
     }

 }); 
}
```

The xml which is used:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- headline, optional -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:id="@+id/mainHeadlineWrapper"
                  android:visibility="gone">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" style="@style/headlineBox">
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/listHeader"
                      android:textColor="@color/actionbarTextColor"
                      style="@style/myDefaultTextAppearance.headline"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/mainHeadlineDivider" android:background="@color/mainHeadlineDividerBg"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- search wrapper -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mainListSearchWrapper" android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <!-- main listView -->
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_listView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This error only occurs on a Samsung table (SM-T311, android 4.4.2) so far. I could not reproduce it on a Moto G or on an Asus tablet.

I have no idea how to locate the error. I cannot find anything in the error log which would point me to the reason for crashing.

If you do not know an answer to this particular error maybe you can tell me what could be different when the app is active and visible and when it is not.

Thank you for your help.

**[EDIT]**
I should have mentioned that I tried "keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" and android:screenOrientation="portrait".
Nothing worked.

**[EDIT]**
I changed the text to make my question more understandable.
I searched for crashes on screen orientation change while the app is not visible / closed / in background but I found only the usual issues with handling orientation change.

**[EDIT]**

With the activity in the manifest like the following, the app crashes both active and stopped (invisible, androids home screen visible):

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With the activity in the manifest like the following, the app crashes only when stopped (invisible, androids home screen visible) and changes from portrait to landscape just fine:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
          >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With the activity in the manifest like the following, the app crashes only when stopped (invisible, androids home screen visible) and does not change from portrait to landscape as expected:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Focus on `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=24; index=230`. You can show where you are `inflating your view` at least so we can say something

Comment: I added the code where I am inflating my view and the xml.

Comment: I have no idea which array is meant. The list which is shown in the ListView has no size of 24. How can I find out which array is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" in your manifest and code must be like this

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
```

Comment: Funny enough, I just tried it with `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` and without `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and now the app crashes also when active and visible on orientation change. If I use neither `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` nor `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` the app changes from portrait to landscape just fine. See my third [EDIT] with manifest samples.

Comment: And thank you for your answer. I can see that my question was voted down (thus I tried to make it clearer by editing it). Thank you that you try to help anyway.